# Why was my answer to "Is there a Christian position on cadaveric organ donation?" deleted?

Tags: discussion

My answer to [the above question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/52142/is-there-a-christian-position-on-cadaveric-organ-donation/52143?noredirect=1#comment142086_52143) (which is now on hold) was deleted with the comment:

> Please don't answer broad qusetions from a single perspective. If they
>   are answerable at all on this site they need to be covered as an
>   overview from all available views. Otherwise the questions themselves
>   need to be refocused until they are answerable. Answering from
>   "viewpoint X" on a question that could just as well be answered from
>   "viewpoint Y" ruins the Q&A format by encouraging vote contents
>   between viewpoints rather than sorting answers by quality of answer
>   representing the same information.

Firstly, my answer was not from a single perspective:  It contained references from both Eastern Orthodox and Roman Catholic sources.

Secondly, Roman Catholics and Eastern Orthodox together comprise around 60% of Christians worldwide, so one could argue that the points I cited represent the views of the majority of Christians.

Is there any kind of a review process for when one member decides to delete another member's answer?

Comment: A couple notes: Caleb is a moderator, as indicated by the diamond next to his name, so he's one of only a few trusted users with broad deletion capabilities.  And this, the meta site, is indeed the correct place to ask for a review.

Answer (score 6):

The real problem here was the question. It's a classic "Truth" question looking for  what *the* Christian position is. This is a question format we actively avoid because they turn into vote contests between theological positions. As an answerer you should be on the lookout for questions like these and flag them for closure rather than answering them.

I deleted your answer because the question was closed as it isn't fair to leave answers that will be controversial under closed truth question. Inevitably somebody comes along and whines about not being able to answer with *their* version of the truth or start a debate thread in comments.

If a question comes along that fits the site guidelines and is properly scoped I would encourage you to put your answer under than question, but as long as the question itself is so completely contrary to our site guidelines and remains closed, allowing some answers under it is just too problematic.